# Sticky Transition div using hero 100vh

Tags: javascript, css

I'm having a bit of trouble with my code below I want the div with text to stay ad the bottom of the hero with the background transparent then when that div gets to the top it sticks with a black background. my issue is that I have to set it in the javascript very high 900 which I know is a bad idea because it will not act right in small screens how can I control that by screen I tried doing 90% from top and it didn't work.

also my bg image on scroll fades out to black but again I have to set the scroll to 900 what is the best way to accomplish this?

when you return back the stick div goes below the hero making it bigger

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".hero-background").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 900);
  });
$(document).scroll(function() {
  //detect when user scroll to top and set position to relative else sets position to fixed
  $(".sticky").css({
    "top": "0",
    "background-color": "black",
    "position": $(this).scrollTop() > 900 ? "fixed" : "relative"
  });
});
```

```css
.hero {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}

.hero-background {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-egOH8RkBAu0/UQfDNRSwC9I/AAAAAAAAeps/5Ay3wbD0Ihk/s1600/ice-snowy-rocks-mountains-hd-background-wallpapers-widescreen-high-resolutions-025.jpg');
  background-position: 50% 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.block {
  height: 1500px;
}

.sticky {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 55px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hero" id="hero">
    <div class="hero-background"></div>
    <div class="sticky">
      <div class="text-block">This is some text inside of a div block.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Have you considered using media queries? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Instead of using 900, you need to get the ofset top of the div element when you scroll and when the window scrollTop gets to the div offset top then you dock it (make it sticky). This would result in the div sticking to the top as soon as it gets to the top of the viewport.

Comment: @Huangism I gave sticky and ID how can I make it to if sticky div is 0 top class the sticky I'm not to familiar with javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a constant 900, get the offset top of the div and set fixed position when you pass that point. Also need to get the offset top again when you resize because your content will change the position of the offset

https://jsfiddle.net/zc5Lbd8a/2/

JS

```
// cache sticky div
var $sticky = $(".sticky");

// cache offset top when page loads
var stickyOffset = $sticky.offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {

  if( $(this).scrollTop() >= stickyOffset ) {
    $sticky.addClass('docked');
  } else {
    $sticky.removeClass('docked');
  }

});

$(window).resize( function() {
  // get offset top again when resizing
    stickyOffset = $sticky.offset().top;
});
```

CSS

```
.sticky {
  top: 0;
  height: 55px;
  color: red;
}
.docked {
  background-color: #000;
  position: fixed;
}
```

HTML was not edited, css was updated to make it simpler and in the js I am adding a class instead of setting css props each time

Comment: is it possible to do the same with the hero-background opacity?

Comment: @Codi see https://jsfiddle.net/zc5Lbd8a/3/ instead of 900 you want to use the height of the hero div